# what is the Time complexity of this function

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

How to calculate time complexity of this function step by step ?

This function converts an adjacency list to a matrix, manipulate the matrix and then convert the matrix back to a list

```
Graphe *Graphe::grapheInverse( void ){
    
    Graphe *r = new Graphe (_adjacences.size() );
    
    std::vector<vector<int> > matrix(_adjacences.size(), vector<int>( _adjacences.size() ) );
    
    std::vector<vector<int> > liste(matrix.size());

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < _adjacences.size(); i++)
        for (auto j : *_adjacences[i])
            matrix[i][j] = 1;


    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 1)
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
            else 
                matrix[i][j] = 1;
            if (i == j)
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); j++){
            if (matrix[i][j] == 1){
                liste[i].push_back(j);
            }
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < liste.size(); i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < liste[i].size(); j++) {
            r->ajouterArcs( i, liste[i][j] );        
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any experimental results? It can actually answer your question, or at least can be used for verification of analytical results

Comment: what do you mean by results ? a list as an example and what happens ?

Comment: Are you interested in precise or asymptotic time complexity?

Comment: I meant trying for various sizes and measuring the time

Comment: just O(n) = what ? from the answer provided is it O(n) = 4*N^2 ?

Comment: `O(N*N)`, where `N` is the number of entries per row of the matrix.  Too much is required to go over why that is -- that is a large topic dealt with better by algorithm books.

Comment: Are you familiar with "Big O" notation?

Comment: @adam -- If the matrix were not always square as yours is (i.e. a ragged 2D array), then the "Big O" would depend on the total number of entries overall, as opposed to being strictly `N*N`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Note that the following all applies to big-O time complexity:***

Calculating the time complexity involves looking at how many times you iterate over the data.  One for loop is N, as you touch each point once. A nested for loop (for i in data, for j in data) is N^2 because you touch each point once for each point there is.

A for loop next to a for loop (For i in data do X, for i in data do Y) touches the data N + N times.  This is still considered N time complexity because as N approaches a very large number, 2N doesn't make much difference.  The same goes for nested loops, N^2+N^2 = 2N^2 -> Essentially, you would ignore any multipliers, and go based on the times you touch N. That means 2N^2 changes to ***N^2***

***To reiterate, this is specifically for big-O time complexity***

Comment: so this is equal to: 4*N^2 ?

Comment: Please consider editing the answer emphasizing the "big-O" detail :-)

Comment: @adam no, the answer is `N^2`, as the constants are ignored

Comment: @PeteBecker You're right, I meant N^2+N^2, I've changed the answer to reflect this.

Comment: The reason that "constants are ignored" is that they drop out. If you double the size of the input data, it doesn't matter whether an algorithm touches the data N times or 2N times. Doubling the size of the input data doubles the time that the algorithm takes, regardless of what N is multiplied by. That's what O(whatever) is about: it measures how the time needed increases when you increase the size of the input.